# Remove this unused method parameter in spring-security @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring-security, sonarqube

I have major issue "Remove this unused method parameter "shiftId"" (and some similar issues):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/refund/{invoiceId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("@AccessPosition.toMeOpen(#shiftId)")
public PosTransactionRefundInfoDTO getTransactionRefund(@PathVariable("shiftId") Long shiftId, @PathVariable("invoiceId") Long invoiceId)
{
    // ... some code here
}
```

Parameter `shiftId` declared only for `@PreAuthorize`annotation, it's not used somwhere in method code.
Can I fix this issue somehow "in a right way", without marking it with "wont fix" or "false positive"?

Comment: You might start a discussion around this on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should be handled by this ticket - https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1691

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that it is not a logical/design error: Why authorize on something that you don't use? Can this cause a security hole?

To get rid of warning, I would suggest use the method parameter in a simple logging statement:

```java
logger.debug("ShiftId: {}", shiftId);
```